# how to get list of transitive dependencies required for my java application?

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle, maven-3

We have a requirement to build all dependencies from source code which we are deploying as part of application deployment, so here is my question how to get  list of transitive dependencies ( 4th/5th to nth party dependancies) which are required in my application class path.

Example :
I have third party dependancy spring-core-5.2.6 version, when I build this jar from source in my local gradle cache folder it’s downloaded 220+ dependencies, but when I build my application and deployed in to server then I can see in application class path 150+ dependencies only ( this 150+ is including other 20 third party dependancies and it’s transitive dependencies).
Now the question is in that 150 jars what are the list of transitive dependencies which are coming from spring-core-5.2.6 ?
Is there any plugins or any solutions are available in java?

Comment: This is specific to your build system. You tagged with both Maven and Gradle, but answers for Maven won't apply to Gradle. (Also, your "requirement" is completely insane, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Why do you want to build everything from source? This is very unusual.

Answer (score 1):

`mvn dependency:tree` is the command that will give you all of your dependencies and of their transitive dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The scope can also affect transitive dependencies.A dependency with the scope compile, will bring its dependencies with scope compile and runtime in your main project, but will not bring those with scope test/provided, see this [doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope)